# vue v-for comparing data in current loop with the last loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I am running a loop in my vue component that looks like this,

```
<entry v-for="(entry, index) in today" :place="place" :user="entry" :key="index"/>
```

I have a place prop that I want to either show the index of the loop or an "=" if the `score` property in entry is the same as the last item the loop rendered is this possible to do?

I had tried running,

```js
renderPlace(index, score) {
  let place = "";
  if (score === this.lastScore) {
    place = "=";
  } else {
    place = addOrdinal(index + 1);
  }

  this.lastScore = score;
  return place;
},
```

on the `:place` prop but this warns me that my loop maybe infinite. So I'm a bit stuck now.

Comment: `that looks like this,` it's invisible - indent `<entry v-for="(entry, index) in today" :place="place" :user="entry" :key="index"/>` by 4 spaces so it appears in the question :p

Comment: `as the last item` last as in the final  entry? `today[today.length - 1]` or last as in the previous entry? `today[index - 1]`